# Performance difference in Jython and Java implementations of a turbo decoder

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jython, decoding

I'm currently making a Computer Science thesis on a multithreaded software implementation of a turbo decoder. The basic problem is as follows:

- let (y1, ..., yn) be the sequence of noisy bit received through a channel. Two SISO decoders work in parallel (each one receiving the first bit of the sequence and the parity bit y1j, j in {1,2}) - the objective is to compute the LLR (log-likelyhood ratio, which gives info on the probability that the current bit is either 0 or 1), which is then fed to the other SISO decoder for the next iteration. Suppose the received bits are split into shorter frames of data. (SISO means soft input, soft output, because each decoder gets an estimation of the bit probabilities in input and outputs its own estimation)

Each computation of the LLR requires lots of serialized ACS operations, depending on the amount of the bits in each frames (and on the amount of bits used by the encoder to make the parity bits for the initial sequence). Such computation can be summed with these nested for cycles (for each one of the two SISO decoders working in parallel):

> `for i=1 to N_FRAMES:`
>
> > `for j=1 to N_ELS_FRAMES:`
> >
> > > `for k=1 to 4:`
> > >
> > > > `for l=1 to N_STATES:`
> > > >
> > > > > `do_ops()`

Note that the above loop doesn't actually appear in the algorithm, but it does match quite closely the operations made for each iteration. Generally, N_STATES is around 8 or 16 (it depends on the amount of bits each encoder uses to compute the parity bits on the input sequence) and do_ops() requires a sum, a max and a vector normalization.

At first I tried to make an implementation using Jython, but the result was pretty disheartening: the operations in the nested loops above took - with the multithreaded version - around 20 minutes (!) with a moderate (~2 mil) amount of bits.

On the other hand, a Java implementation requires ~1 sec with ~4 mil bits using the single-threaded version of the algorithm.

Why is there such a huge difference?